# UISplitViewController with header

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I need to add UIScrollView in the top of UISplitViewController's view (so it will be common for all split views in this controller). At first I though about [self.mySplitViewController.view addSubview:self.myScrollView]. 
But may be it exists better solution.

**Update**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting the UIScrollView in the detail or master view of the UISplitViewController?

Comment: I want, it would be 1024 px width, so scroll view should be in the top of both detail and master views. Look at the picture in the update.

Comment: Are you wanting the UIScrollViewController to cover (and therefore hide) the UISplitViewController? It doesn't make sense to me otherwise.

Comment: 1) I want scroll view, not scroll view controller. Look at the image. Top part is scroll view. detail + master = split view controller.